# Force a lonely float to top of page

Tags: floats, positioning

I am not fond of solitary floats "floating" in the middle page. Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

How can I force the "C" image to top of page without affecting the harmony of "A" and "B" images floating symmetrically throughout the page? It means `H` is not an option.

Comment: @JouleV it doesnt't work even as `t!`.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong